# map using geojson file in AMCHARTS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, geojson, amcharts

I am quite new to javascript and I am having a hard time reproducing [this example](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/using-geojson-maps-amcharts/) of amcharts map from geojson format exactly like the one illustrated. What I did to try to reproduce locally: I created the files `index.css`, `index.js` and `index.html` and copied the codes from each of the tabs in the example on them. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you include jQuery?

Comment: So what error did you see in your browser's console: Right click > Inspect > Console?

Comment: index.html:2 GET file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geojson2svg/1.0.2/geojson2svg.min.js net::ERR_INVALID_URL
index.html:3 GET file://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js net::ERR_INVALID_URL
index.html:4 GET file://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js net::ERR_INVALID_URL
index.html:5 GET file://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Comment: I have not included <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> but I have tried later and did not work as well

Comment: the filepaths were missing `https://` and also Jquery not included before, thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have Included Jquery.js before Index.js.
Also include geojson2svg(https://github.com/gagan-bansal/geojson2svg) library which is mentioned in tutorial.

Happy Coding!!!!